# 置換したいです。行数がすごく多くなってきました。

Tags: php, 正規表現

今、phpで将棋のプログラムを書いています。
盤面のマスに2をいれると、歩兵を置きます。
盤面のマスに1をいれると、仲人を置きます。（仲人は駒の名前）
盤面のマスに0をいれると、何も駒を置きません。

駒の種類が１５０種類あるので、手作業ではなくて置換を使いたいと思っています。
index.phpというファイルに関数があります。その関数`ban_position($x,$y)`を呼び出すと、`return $koma_name;`で駒の名前を返します。

```
//関数です。
 function ban_position($x,$y){
    global $koma_position;
    if ($koma_position [$x][$y]==0) {
        $koma_name = "　";
    }else if ($koma_position [$x][$y]==1) {
        $koma_name = "仲人";
    }
*
*
*
.
.
//アスタリスクを１５０になるまでたくさん並べます。
.
.
*
*
*//ここが150番目のelse if文にしたいと思っています。
    return $koma_name;
 }
```

何をしたいのかというと、ひとつひとつのアスタリスクを下記のelse if文に置換しようとしてます。

```
else if ($koma_position [$x][$y]==▲▲) {
    $koma_name = "★★";
}
```

このelse if文の★★部分をpos_data.txtに書いてある150種類の駒の名前に置換しようとしています。
そのときに、▲▲部分をそれぞれの駒の名前に対応する番号に置換しようとしています。
理想図↓

```
 function ban_position($x,$y){
    global $koma_position;
    if ($koma_position [$x][$y]==0) {
        $koma_name = "　";
    }else if ($koma_position [$x][$y]==1) {
        $koma_name = "仲人";
    }else if ($koma_position [$x][$y]==2) {
        $koma_name = "歩兵";
    }else if ($koma_position [$x][$y]==3) {
        $koma_name = "飛車";
    }else if ($koma_position [$x][$y]==4) {
        $koma_name = "左車";
    }else if ($koma_position [$x][$y]==5) {
        $koma_name = "右車";
    }
*
*
*
.
.//150番目まで続く。
.
*
*
*
    return $koma_name;
 }
```

gitにindex.phpとpos_data.txtがあります。

https://gist.github.com/Zerosen/033ad85a37f44aeb5a94a902891b737c

教えてくれる方いたら、よろしくお願いします。
pos_data.txtの今回重要な置換したい部分だけ一応ここに貼っておきます。

```
0駒なし
1仲人
2歩兵
3飛車
4左車
5右車
6横行
7横飛
8堅行
9角行
10龍馬
11龍王
12摩羯
13鉤行
14奔王
15驢馬
16桂馬
17猛牛
18飛龍
19羅刹
20夜叉
21力士
22金剛
23狛犬
24老鼠
25嗔猪
26盲熊
27悪狼
28麒麟
29鳳凰
30師子
31反車
32猫叉
33淮鶏
34古猿
35蟠蛇
36臥龍
37猛豹
38盲虎
39醉象
40香車
41土将
42石将
43瓦将
44鉄将
45銅将
46銀将
47金将
48提婆
49無明
50玉将
100駒なし
101奔人
102金
103金
104金
105金
106金
107金
108金
109金
110成らず
111成らず
112金
113金
114成らず
115金
116金
117金
118金
119金
120金
121金
122金
123金
124蝙蝠
125奔猪
126奔熊
127奔狼
128師子
129奔王
130成らず
131金
132奔猫
133仙鶴
134山母
135奔蛇
136奔龍
137奔豹
138奔虎
139王子
140金
141奔土
142奔石
143奔瓦
144奔鉄
145奔銅
146奔銀
147奔金
148教王
149法性
150自在王
```

Comment: 行数が多く編集しきれないということですと、コーディング方針が間違っていると思われます。正規表現で置換できるような類似コードの繰り返しということは、ループで表現できるはずであり、設計を見直すことをお勧めします。

Comment: やってみます。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 数字をコマ名に置き換えたいなら、この場合は置換ではなく「配列」を使った方がスマートな気がします。また、同じような処理の繰り返しも`if-else`文を並べるより`for`文などのループを使った方が楽が出来るでしょう。

Comment: [XY 問題とは？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2702/25936)が質問をより良くする参考になると思いました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やってみます。