# 投票結果を投票数が多い順に並べ替えて表示したい

Tags: php, sort

以下の関数を実行すると、上から投票数が多い順に

```
（例）
1.13.1.14: 8回
5.11.5.12: 3回
2.13.3.14: 1回
```

（1.13.1.14の部分が投票内容）
といった感じで表示されるはずなんですが、たぶんソートの部分が間違ってて一番大きい投票結果が並び続けてしまいます。

```
（例）
1.13.1.14: 8回
1.13.1.14: 8回
1.13.1.14: 8回
```

教えてくれる方いたらよろしくおねがします。

追記

"投票内容"の中身は数値。今回は18になっています。
"投票ボタンが押された回数"の中身は、

```
（実際）
3.19.8.13
2.19.8.13
3.19.8.13
3.19.8.13
3.19.8.13
2.19.8.13
2.19.8.13
2.19.8.13
2.19.8.13
2.19.8.13
2.19.8.13
2.19.8.13
2.19.8.13
2.19.8.13
2.19.8.13
2.19.8.13
2.19.7.13
2.19.7.13
```

となっています。理想では、show_votes()を実行すると、

```
（実際）
2.19.8.13:12回
3.19.8.13:4回
2.19.7.13:2回
```

と画面に表示されます。

```
function show_votes(){
    //数えたい。
    $vote_sofar = file("投票内容");
    $times_vote = file_get_contents("投票ボタンが押された回数");
    $int_times_vote = intval($times_vote);
    $vote_sofar_num = array();
    $maximum=0;

    for ($b=0 ; $b<$int_times_vote ; $b++){
        $number=0;
        $flag=0;
        if($b!=0){
            for ($c=$b-1 ; $c>=0 ; $c--){//前に重複があるならスキップして次のループへ。
                if($vote_sofar[$c] == $vote_sofar[$b]){
                    $flag=1;
                }
            }
        }
        if($flag == 1){
            $vote_sofar_num[$b] = -1;
            continue;
        }
        for ($a=0 ; $a<$int_times_vote ; $a++){//以降に重複があればnumberをインクリメント。
            if($vote_sofar[$b]==$vote_sofar[$a]){
                $number++;//おなじ投票内容があれば数え上げる。
            }       
        }
        $vote_sofar_num[$b] = $number;
        //echo $vote_sofar_num[$b];
    }
    $dd = 0;
    for ($b=0 ; $b<$int_times_vote ; $b++){
        $found_max = 0;
        if($vote_sofar_num[$b] > 0){
            for ($d=$b+1 ; $d<$int_times_vote ; $d++){//マキシマムを求める。
            $pos_max=$b;
                if($vote_sofar_num[$b] < $vote_sofar_num[$d]){
                    $maximum = $vote_sofar_num[$d];
                    $pos_max=$d;

                    $found_max = 1; //見つけた。
                }

            }

            //求めたマキシマムと最上の値を交換。
            if ($found_max = 1){
                $vote_sofar_num[$pos_max] = $vote_sofar_num[$b];
                $vote_sofar_num[$b] = $maximum;

                $swap = $vote_sofar[$pos_max];
                $vote_sofar[$pos_max] = $vote_sofar[$b];
                $vote_sofar[$b] = $swap;
            }
        }
    }
    for($b=0 ; $b<$int_times_vote ; $b++){//ここで画面に表示。
        if($vote_sofar_num[$b] > 0){

            echo $vote_sofar[$b];
            echo ":";
            echo $vote_sofar_num[$b];
            echo "回\n";

        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: ソートの部分ではなく、数える部分に問題がありそうですが、inputとなるデータがわからないので、それ以上は何とも。`"投票内容"`と`"投票ボタンが押された回数"`の中身(「表示されるはず」のデータに近いもの)をお示しいただけませんか。

Comment: 了解しました。ちょっとまっててください！

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Zerosen/69ac888b757f3ac7b75a0839a8e59dbb

Comment: functions.phpというファイルの４行目にfunction show_votes()があります。関数たちが入ってるfunction.phpは、ほかのファイル’（index.phpとvote.php）からincludeされています。テキストファイルである"投票内容"とテキストファイルである"投票ボタンが押された回数"はgitの一番下のほうにあります。

Comment: 上で張ったgitのURL先に、今とりかかってるファイルが複数あります。

Comment: リンクのご提示ありがとうございます。ただ、回答を書くために極めて重要な情報は、ご質問本文に記載いただけないでしょうか。種々の理由でそのリンク先が非公開になったり書きかえられたりした場合、後からこの質問を読まれた方に質問内容がわからなくなってしまいます。今回の場合、それほど大きなファイルでもないようですし、機密にしなければならない情報もなさそうなので、そのまま全体を質問本文中に追記していただくのが良いと思います。(ご自身の質問は「編集」できます。)ところで`"投票ボタンが押された回数"`ファイルの中身は、必ず`"投票内容"`ファイルの行数と同じになるのでしょうか? だとしたら、わざわざ別ファイルにする意味があまりないような…。

Comment: "投票ボタンが押された回数"ファイルの中身は、必ず"投票内容"ファイルの行数と同じになります。ただ、行数は一番上の行が配列だと0なので、行を指定する場合は-1をつけています。たしかに、言われてみるとそうでした。

Comment: ここもっとこうしたほうがいいよとか言ってくれたら参考にさせてもらいます。

Comment: とりあえず上に書いたようにご質問の編集をしていただけないでしょうか。私の方は今は手一杯なので、このご質問の内容を実際のデータを使って精査するところまでできないのですが、編集することによりアクティブリストの上位にくるので、他の読者の方があなたの質問を見つけやすくなります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

私だったらこうします。
これではだめですかね？

```
function showVotes()
{
    $vote_sofar = file("投票内容");

    //データをためるバケツを用意
    $backet = array();

    foreach($vote_sofar as $one_vote)
    {
        //キーの有無チェック
        if(array_key_exists($one_vote, $backet))
        {
            //既にキーがあれば数をインクリメント
            $num = $backet[$one_vote];
            $num++;
            $backet[$one_vote] = $num;
        }
        else
        {
            //キーが無ければ枠を用意
            $backet[$one_vote] = 1;
        }
    }

    //値で降順並べ替え
    arsort($backet);

    foreach($backet as $key => $value)
    {//ここで画面に表示。
            echo $key;
            echo ":";
            echo $value;
            echo "回\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: すごくうまくいきました。よく読んで、foreachなどを理解しようと思います。

Comment: @zerosen さん、user17014 さんのこの回答がご質問の課題を解決したとお思いなら「承認」の操作をお願いします。(回答の横にチェックマークっぽいものが見えていると思います。)また[別質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/48447/13972)の方も、リンク先を見るといい感じに解決されているように見えます。こちらのサイトでは、自己解決した時には自己回答することが推奨されています。まだ改良途上でしたら落ち着いてからで良いので、そちらも是非お願いします。(ちなみに数百行に渡る長いコードは概要がわかる範囲でうまく省略してくれた方がいいです。)